# change configure variable dynamically cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Let's say I have this in my bootstrap.php file in a cakePHP application:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
```

How can I dynamically change the value of that configuration variable based on user action in a controller of my application? I tried to do the same thing that I did above here in my controller, but that didn't work

Any help?

Comment: The code you posted is correct. Does `Configure::read('Config.language');` not return what you expect? Define "didn't work".

Comment: Well that part's fine, he's trying to change it later on in the execution. Something from this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132465/cakephp-2-1-url-language-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try `Configure::write('Config.language', 'dut');` for e.g.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147349/840409) from the question suggested by @Ryan Pendleton shows a somewhat correct way to use this directive.
It should be used in the AppController because it gets loaded first - as the parent of all other controllers in the application itself.
I used "somewhat correct" because it is best to validate the language codes ('eng', 'fre', 'dut') in the `app/config/routes.php` file - [go here for more information](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/945/Routes-Configuration).

Also do check out this: [Internationalization-Localization explanation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1228/Internationalization-Localization).