# CakePHP adding language parameter to URLs

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, url-routing, cakephp-2.3

I implemented the solution [at this article](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/).

"`beforeFilter`" and "`_setLanguage`" works fine. If URL has language parameter, I can successfully set cookies/session variables. And use it between controllers.

That solution also includes adding `url()` function to `AppHelper`.

```
class AppHelper extends Helper {
   function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        if(!isset($url['language']) && isset($this->params['language'])) {
          $url['language'] = $this->params['language'];
        }
        return parent::url($url, $full);
   }
}
```

But I have many URLs in my View files that are written without using `HtmlHelper`. Like this:

```
// myfile.ctp
<a href="/mypage/">click me plase<a>
```

So it seems like AppHelper::url solution doesn't fix my issue. What would be better alternative to add language prefix to URLs?

I thought defining a global variable like this:

```
// AppController::_beforeFilter()
if ($this->request->params['language'] != "")
{
   Configure::write('URLprefix', '/'.$this->request->params['language']);
} else {
   Configure::write('URLprefix', '');
}
```

Then change view file like this:

```
// myfile.ctp
<a href="<?php echo URLprefix; ?>/mypage/">click me plase<a>
```

But it doesn't seem a good way. Is there a better way to add prefix to URLs. Or should I add to all links by hand ?

Related:
[Adding a prefix to every URL in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794412/adding-a-prefix-to-every-url-in-cakephp)
[CakePHP 2.x i18n route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427391/cakephp-2-x-i18n-route)
[CakePHP 2.1 URL Language Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132465/cakephp-2-1-url-language-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate all links and URLs within your application using [`HtmlHelper::link()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink) and [`HtmlHelper::url()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aurl)

This will make sure that your Routes are taken into account when generating URLs (*Reverse routing*)

For example, if you decide to define a 'friendly' URL Route `/logout` for `/users/logout`, then this:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Log out', array(
    'controller' => 'users', 
    'action' => 'logout'
));
```

Will create this link:

```
<a href='/logout'>Log out</a>
```

If you later decide to modify the 'friendly' URL Route (`/sign-out`) for the logout URL, then all links in your application will automatically be adjusted.

The **same** call to the HtmlHelper, will now output:

```
<a href='/sign-out'>Log out</a>
```

Read more on this subject here:

[Reverse Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#reverse-routing)